# Enforcing community wiki content

Tags: support, community-wiki

Already quite a few posts has surfaced that should be made community wiki content. Classics like "where do i find material for taking SharePoint certification" etc that has many objective answers are good answers, but to awoid "horing" for rep they should be marked as CW.

On SPO this worked pretty snappy, though it seems there always were 4-5 answers with lots of rep before it was changed to CW.

Same thing now on SPSE, though it seems to take longer time to get the Q's marked.

1) Can "normal" users mark others posts as CW when they get a certain rep, or can we still only mark for moderator?

2) How much rep does it take for one asking a question to be able to mark a Q as CW?

3) Also on SPO we had a special article we referred to, so that newcomers who asked the Q in good faith had an explanation on why it should be marked as CW. Could we get that article moved/revived? All we got so far is this article that we could refer to [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Is it right to **require** contributors to mark their contributions community wiki, knowing that it deprives them of reputation growth based off of these CW-marked contributions? See also:

http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/is-it-really-bad-to-post-separate-partial-answers-and-invite-people-to-vote-on-t

Answer (score 4):

We have provided some additional guidance at the blog:

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

TL;DR version

> Most of the time, you should be asking yourself “How can I improve this post so that community wiki isn’t needed?” Community wiki is like a cheese knife: it is a specialized tool to be used sparingly, and only in very specific circumstances.

Comment: I can't vote this up high enough. **This is a must read and no excuse for TL;DR!**

Answer (score 3):

Questions can no longer be made community wiki by the author. If you wish to have a question made community wiki, flag it for moderator attention. Individual *answers* can be made community wiki, however.

Comment: Interesting! Whats the reasoning behind authors not being able to create a CW question? Quite often these Q's are relevant but too open to be considered a "real" question, it would be helpful if the author could do this himself when Q is created, not hours later when we got 5 answers with 5 upvotes each

Comment: @Anders Rask: It became evident that they the Community Wiki feature was not well-understood and was being used incorrectly more often than not. You can read more about the discussion that prompted this change here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better

Comment: ok then, please advice on how to treat totally open Q like the new "how to explan SharePoint to an alien" thats already being upvoted and getting answers http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11449/how-to-explain-sharepoint-to-an-alien this kind of open Q's doesnt really add any value IMO (might just be me)

Comment: @Anders Rask: If it **adds no value**, close it. That's *exactly* why use of community wiki removed on questions. Wiki was *never* to be used as "this question isn't very good so let's make it community wiki." Case and point.

Answer (score -2):

You can edit posts at 500 prestige:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit
I think you're able to change it then, but I can't test to verify.

The link you provided explains how to convert it into a CW:

> How does a post become a Community
>   Wiki post?
>
> There are several ways a question or
>   answer can enter community wiki mode,
>   and most of these ways will occur
>   automatically based on the rules of
>   the system.
>
> Posts enter community wiki mode when
>   one of the following happens:
>
> ```
> * The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different
> ```
>
> users.
>       * The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.
>       * The answer's author checks the community wiki checkbox when composing
>   the answer. Note that this checkbox
>   isn't available to new users.
>       * The answer is edited by its original author, who when doing so
>   opts to check the community wiki.
>       * An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community
>   Wiki. Note that when a question is
>   made CW after answers have already
>   been posted, the existing answers are
>   not normally converted to CW
>   automatically.
>       * The question generates more than 30 answers (15 on Super User). In this
>   case, the question and all answers
>   will enter community mode, as will any
>   future answers.
>       * A moderator has reason to believe that the question serves
>   better in community wiki mode - if you
>   want your question to be converted to
>   a Community Wiki, flag it for
>   moderator attention.
>
> - note that the rules outlined above are based on observations; the actual
>     behavior of SO is subject to change
>     without notice, and may well have done
>     so since this was last updated...

I however tried to reply and make my reply a CW, but that didn't change the original post into CW. So I flagged for moderation attention right now.